# Second generalized Bernoulli number $B_{2,\chi}$

Tags: number-theory, characters, bernoulli-numbers, bernoulli-polynomials

Let be $\chi$ (non-trivial) Dirichlet charakter of conductor $f$. Then I know that $$B_{n,\chi}=f^{n-1}\sum_{a=1}^f\chi(a)B_n\left(\frac{a}{f}\right).$$
Assume $\chi(-1)=1$  and plug $n=2,$ then $$B_{2,\chi}=f\sum_{a=1}^f\chi(a)\left(\frac{a^2}{f^2}-\frac{a}{f}+\frac{1}{6}\right).$$
Using $\sum_{a=1}^f\chi(a)=0$ I get
$$B_{2,\chi}=\frac{1}{f}\sum_{a=1}^f\chi(a)a^2-\sum_{a=1}^f\chi(a)a.$$
I would like to show that the second sum equals to $0,$ but I don't know how to do it. I haven't used the assumption $\chi(-1)=1$ yet, but I don't see why it is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sum_{a=1}^f\chi(a)a=\sum_{a=1}^{f-1}\chi(a)a=\sum_{a=1}^{f-1}(f-a)\chi(f-a)=\sum_{a=1}^{f-1}(f-a)\chi(a)$$
$$\Rightarrow2\sum_{a=1}^{f-1}\chi(a)a=f\sum_{a=1}^{f-1}\chi(a)=0$$